# Injecting variables to my NextJS app using Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, next.js

I'm trying to generate some env variables when I'm deploying my code with Kubernets. What I'm trying to do is to generate a ConfigMap to get my variables, but it's not working.
I'm using azure pipelines to do my build and publish steps.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json .

COPY . .

RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

My azure-pipelines.yml:

```
stages:
#Build Dev
- stage: BuildDev
  displayName: Build and Push Dev
  jobs:
  - job: Development
    displayName: Build and Push Dev
    timeoutInMinutes: 0
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - task: Docker@1
      displayName: Build Image
      inputs:
        azureSubscriptionEndpoint: my-subscription
        azureContainerRegistry: my-container-registry
        command: build
        imageName: tenant/front/dev:$(Build.BuildId)
        includeLatestTag: true
        buildContext: '**'
    - task: Docker@1
      displayName: Push Image
      inputs:
        azureSubscriptionEndpoint: my-subscription
        azureContainerRegistry: my-container-registry
        command: push
        imageName: tenant/front/dev:$(Build.BuildId)
        buildContext: '**'


#Deploy Dev
- stage: DeployDev
  displayName: Deploy Dev
  jobs:
    - deployment: Deploy
      displayName: Deploy Dev
      timeoutInMinutes: 0
      pool:
        vmImage: ubuntu-18.04
      environment: Development-Front
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - task: Kubernetes@1
              displayName: 'kubectl apply'
              inputs:
                kubernetesServiceEndpoint: 'AKS (standard subscription)'
                command: apply
                useConfigurationFile: true
                configurationType: inline
                inline: |
                  apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
                  kind: Deployment
                  metadata:
                      name: $(appNameDev)
                      labels:
                          app: $(appNameDev)
                  spec:
                      replicas: 1
                      selector:
                          matchLabels:
                              app: $(appNameDev)
                      template:
                          metadata:
                              labels:
                                  app: $(appNameDev)
                          spec:
                              containers:
                                  - name: $(appNameDev)
                                    image: tenant/front/dev:$(Build.BuildId)
                                    imagePullPolicy:
                                    env:
                                      - name: NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_API
                                        value: development
                                    ports:
                                      - name: http
                                        containerPort: 80
                                        protocol: TCP
                                    volumeMounts:
                                      - name: environment-variables
                                        mountPath: /usr/src/app/.env
                                        readOnly: true
                              volumes:
                                - name: environment-variables
                                  configMap:
                                    name: environment-variables
                                    items:
                                    - key: .env
                                      path: .env
              ---
              apiVersion: v1
              kind: Service
              metadata:
                  name: $(appNameDev)
                  labels:
                      app: $(appNameDev)
              spec:
                  type: LoadBalancer
                  ports:
                      - port: 80
                        targetPort: 80
                        protocol: TCP
                        name: http
                  selector:
                      app: $(appNameDev)
              ---
              apiVersion: v1
              kind: ConfigMap
              metadata:
                name: environment-variables
              data:
                .env: |
                  NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_API=development
                  API=http://another.endpoint.com/serverSide
```

When I'm trying to access this NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_API variable, I'm receiving undefined. In my next.config.js, I'm exporting the variable as publicRuntimeConfig.

Comment: Did u figure it out? I have the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't solve it. I'm still making 3 builds for the different environments.

Comment: I solved it injecting the environment variables while building the docker image using GitHub actions.

Comment: @LeandroHoffmann can you elaborate? Im stuck on the same thing

Comment: @LeandroHoffmann I'm also interested in your solution

Comment: @AustinC just published it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using GitHub actions, the first thing is to add a step in your image build process to include dynamic variables

```
  - name: Create variables
    id: vars
    run: |
      branch=${GITHUB_REF##*/}
      echo "API_URL=API_${branch^^}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      echo "APP_ENV=APP_${branch^^}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      echo "BASE_URL=BASE_${branch^^}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      sed -i "s/GIT_VERSION/${{ github.sha }}/g" k8s/${branch}/api-deployment.yaml
```

The second step is to build the docker image with extra arguments, if you are using another CI, just add the variables directly in the build args as below:

```
--build-arg PROD_ENV=NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=${{ secrets[env.API_URL] }}\nNEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL=${{ secrets[env.BASE_URL]}}\nNEXT_PUBLIC_APP_ENV=${{ secrets[env.APP_ENV] }}
```

Pay attention to the `\n` to skip lines and docker to be able to understand that you are sending multiple variables to the build process.

The last thing is to add the extra args inside the Dockerfile

```
# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM node:16.13.0-alpine AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:16.13.0-alpine AS builder
ARG PROD_ENV=""
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
RUN printf "$PROD_ENV" >> .env.production
RUN yarn build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM node:16.13.0-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

# You only need to copy next.config.js if you are NOT using the default configuration
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/.env* ./
COPY --from=builder /app/next-i18next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001
RUN chown -R nextjs:nodejs /app/.next
USER nextjs

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry.
RUN npx next telemetry disable

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

I send as extra args PROD_ENV and then build a .env.production file on the fly with the required values.

Mark as answer if it helps you